Oneplus Bluetooth neckband not connectind to Ubuntu 24.04.1
I recently switched to ubuntu from windows, i have Oneplus bluetooth Z2 which work completely fine with all other devices but is not connecting to my laptop now, this problem was not on Windows, and also not on Archcraft which i tried for sometime in the same laptop.
it is also now not even discovering my neckband.
i had already tried some methods from the forum, but its has not worked yet.
